# The same component mapped in Private and regular route with different paths - works as in Private route for both

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, logout

I implemented auto-login via SSO for my root path "/" to simplify user's life by redirecting to "/login" with PrivateRoute and it works fine - it redirects to /login if not logged in and authenticates via SSO:

```
const Routes = () => (
<div className="view-routes">
<ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
<ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/loggedout" component={HomePanel} />
<Switch>
  <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/logout" component={Logout} />
  <PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomePanel} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER]} />
</Switch>
</div>
);
```

The problem is my Logout component which looks like:

```
export class Logout extends React.Component<ILogoutProps> {
 componentDidMount() {
    this.props.logout();
 }

render() {
 return (
  <div className="p-5">
    <h4>Logged out successfully!</h4>
    <Redirect
      to={{
        pathname: '/loggedout'
      }}
    />
  </div>
 );
 }
}
```

As you can see in Routes, /loggedout is mapped to the same HomePanel, but this time via "regular" route which should avoid automatic authentication.
It does log out, but when redirected to /loggedout for some reason it immediately after goes to "/" path which causes autologin again.

My question is: why doesn't it simply draw my HomePanel, but instead works as if It went through PrivateRoute again? In case it is how react is supposed to work how should I handle logout in such situation?

Answer (score 0):

Your Switch statement is not correctly placed as it only validates `/logout` and `/`. If the user vistits `/login`, `/loggedout`. in both cases the respective Route will be rendered along with the `/` route

Change your code to

```
const Routes = () => (

    <div className="view-routes">
        <Switch>
          <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/login" component={Login} />
          <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/loggedout" component={HomePanel} />
          <ErrorBoundaryRoute path="/logout" component={Logout} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/" component={HomePanel} hasAnyAuthorities={[AUTHORITIES.USER]} />
        </Switch>

    </div>

);
```

Comment: Thank you. It was one of the reasons. The other one was that logout() method had return url:

Answer (score 0):

Ok. React works as it should work and it is possible to use the same component in private and regular route.

The issue was caused by the fact that logout method has return url:

```
export const logout = () => dispatch => {
  window.location.href = SAML_LOGOUT + `?return=${encodeURIComponent(LOGOUT_URL)}`;
};
```

So, redirect happened twice: one time in logout method and other time in  component. I changed them to the same value and it works fine now.